# How to list files in a .so file?

Tags: linker

Is there any way to list the files used while creating .so file? `nm` cannot be useful and also `readelf' also. Does some table maintain information?

Answer (score 2):

readelf -s libfoobar.so | grep FILE

Answer (score 1):

you cannot list the object files used to create a shared object file, since that information is not stored by default in a shared object file. A shared library is fully linked so you cannot "unarchive" it. see [reference](http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.programmer/command-to-list-contents-of-shared-objec/237158), but you can list the functions contained using this command

```
nm -D /usr/lib/libopenal.so.1
```